# Alternative to Matlab cell data-structure in Python

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures, cell

I have a Matlab cell array, each of whose cells contains an N x M matrix. The value of M varies across cells.

What would be an efficient way to represent this type of a structure in Python using numpy or any standard Python data-structure?

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be a dictionnary d={key: numpy.array([N,M]) ). You can iterate over it and access elements by key, however you lose the possibility to access by position.

Comment: A list is probably the closest thing in Python to a Matlab cell array. It can hold mixed types, like matrices of different sizes. (See Shai's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered a list of `numpy.array`s?

Comment: Yes, I think this might be the simplest thing to do for now. The dictionary idea isn't the best, because I would be accessing the arrays by their position in the list. Thanks!